# Why has "May Crisis ... tests?" been closed without participation of members of our community?

Tags: discussion

Since I observed that "*May Crisis Pregnancy Centers provide false negative results of pregnancy tests?*" has been closed by Shog9 without the participation of other members of this great community, I want to ask whether these unilateral actions done by these so-called *supermods* are ethically correct in general, and whether they are correct on this particular stack that has great moderators and great high-rep users who, if any, can do, as they do everyday, any activity to make this site the great and planetary site it is?

Comment: The issue is actually being discussed here: http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/2626/96 do you mind if we close this question so not to spread the attention of the community?

Comment: @Skliv., what does it mean "do you mind if we close this question so not to spread the attention of the community?" I don't understand it, sorry.

Comment: Che chiudiamo questa domanda e spostiamo la discussione sull'altra per non disperdere il discorso.

Comment: @Sklivvz Even in English, I had to read it a few times... I'm assuming you mean "so not to *split* the attention of *this* community". I first read it as "so not to disseminate the attention of the community".

Comment: That's what I meant.

Comment: @Sklivv, OK, I don't have anything against that procedure. Here or there I would like to know what the community's perspective on this matter is.

Answer (score 5):

SE employees generally avoid acting as moderators on individual sites, but it happens in some situations. Typically this is triggered by the post causing some kind of trouble which draws their attention.

I don't see any problem with this, even when I disagree with their decision, the fact that they intervened at all is usually a sign that there is some issue there that needs to be solved. And the community as well as us moderators are free to override such a decision of an SE employee.